# Getting NaN value on server side for upddateQuantity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

after sending integer value from the client side to server side, I gettting NaN value for the updateQuanity. Whats the solution for this. I am using react and mongodb/express for this.

Client side code:
[Client side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrOEN.png)

Server side:
[server side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mzw6.png)

Comment: the key on the server side should be totalQuantity

Comment: The problem is that pictures don't execute code